# Format the nested property serialized json

Tags: json.net, servicestack-text

I have a CSV string, and one of it's column value is json serialized.

```
"Id,Name,Seo\r\n13,SpecialCollections,\"{\"\"SeoUrl\"\":\"\"special-collections\"\",\"\"SeoPageTitle\"\":null,\"\"SeoKeywords\"\":null,\"\"SeoDescription\"\":null}\"\r\n";
```

I'm using a combination of `JSON.NET` and `ServiceStack.Text` to serialize and deserialize my data from `json-csv` and vice versa.

So, with the above `CSV`input, I first convert it to .NET object using ServiceStack.Text helper method

```
var obj= csvInput.FromCsv<List<dynamic>>();
```

and that gives me an output in a form of `Dictionary<string,string>` for each row of csv

```
1) {[Id, 13]} 
2) {[Name, SpecialCollections]}
3) {[Seo, {"SeoUrl":"special-collections","SeoPageTitle":null,"SeoKeywords":null,"SeoDescription":null}]}
```

Then I serialized the above output with JSON.NET helper method and write in a file which looks like this

```
var serializedJson = JsonConvert
                .SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
```

**Result**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "13",
    "Name": "SpecialCollections",
    "Seo": "{\"SeoUrl\":\"special-collections\",\"SeoPageTitle\":null,\"SeoKeywords\":null,\"SeoDescription\":null}"
  }
]
```

The issue is with nested property 'Seo', although it's value is serialized json but that is because it is `string`, `JSON.NET` treat as a `string` and doesn't format it. Anyway, I can obtain the below expected result?

**Expected Result:**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "13",
    "Name": "SpecialCollections",
    "Seo":  {
        "SeoUrl": "special-collections",
        "SeoPageTitle": null,
        "SeoKeywords": null,
        "SeoDescription": null
      }
  }
]
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "Seo" value is already a JSON string, you'll need to deserialize it into a temporary object (such as a JObject) then recombine it with the other key-value pairs into a new container and serialize that to get the final result you want.  Here is a simple way to do that.

First, create a helper method which can determine whether a string value is JSON or not, and return a JToken from it.

```
public static JToken ToJToken(string s)
{
    if (s == null)
        return JValue.CreateNull();

    // if the string is already JSON, parse it into a JObject (or JArray)
    if ((s.StartsWith("{") && s.EndsWith("}")) || (s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]")))
        return JToken.Parse(s);

    // otherwise create a JValue from the non-JSON string
    return JToken.FromObject(s);
}
```

Then, convert your `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` into a JArray using the above helper method like this:

```
JArray ja = new JArray(
    obj.Select(
        dict => new JObject(
            ((Dictionary<string, string>)dict).Select(
                kvp => new JProperty(kvp.Key, ToJToken(kvp.Value))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Now, to get the formatted JSON you can simply call `ToString()` on the JArray:

```
string json = ja.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VDzGao

Comment: Can I ask you a little more favor? How would you handle if the source become List<Dictionary<string,string>>. I realized, when I do FromCsv<List<dynamic>>, it's producing dynamic result but it is in the form of List<Dictionary<string,string>> instead of Dictionary<string,string>

And since the result is `dynamic`, I don't think the lamda expression would work when creating `JObject`.

Comment: You're right-- I should have noticed that from the square brackets in the JSON in your question.  I've updated my answer and the fiddle.

Comment: As for the dynamic, if the list items are actually Dictionary<string, string> like you said, then you should be able to cast the lambda variable.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can check this updated fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pfuc5w where I tried to convert the string to it's proper type before creating a token. I just wanted to make sure, If I'm doing it correctly or there is a better way to do that. Thanks